# How to set a column as auto increment on an already existing table in MySQL with Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I started database programming yesterday. I wanted to set a `ID` column as auto increment and it tells me to set it as the primary key. However after looking at the columns, I realised there is no primary key column. I suspect this database management tool in visual studio is not a full blown one and I need to use other program to edit this database?

[image]

Comment: Sorry the picture turn out to be very small. I think you need to open it in new tab to see the picture

Comment: is this really MySQL? then why not add tags appropriately ... anyway: your screeny looks more like MSSQL! Do you want to achieve this via GUI or is TSQL-command ok for you?

Comment: sorry this is in visual studio (server explorer). I am confused. My mistake-mySQL is the command I send

Comment: c'mon ... your error-message is pretty clear: you need to make your auto increment a primary key as well ...

Comment: [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [MS SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click left of the ID row (on the square) and use the option "set primary key"
I believe that this should be possible but i'm not quite clear on what program you use.

You could always resort to SQL statements:

```
ALTER TABLE *table name* ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Server Explorer expand the Tables node. After that double-click the table name. In the editor window right-click the column name and select Set Primary Key. For a compound key you must multi-select the columns and right-click.

If that works there should be a little key that appears next to it.

If you're still stuck this just about covers it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZC8h5OChZLg